# Marry an Italian citizen in Italy

Tags: schengen, europe, tourist-visas, weddings, tunisian-citizens

I've a tourist (with a Schengen visa), and I'm going to visit my fiancé in Italy, and also we are planning to get married there. So what papers would I need, and what steps would I need to take?

Helpful information:

- I'm not from the EU.
- She is a student, but she is living alone in her mom's house.
- I got Schengen visa for 90 days issued by the French consulate.

Comment: Marriage is out of scope for Travel. Regarding the immigration aspects, you should ask on expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm not sure how to move it but I will create a topic in expatriates and close this one ?! Correct !

Comment: This can be flagged and be moved. Don't worry about it :) it will go automatically.